# how to show a pop-up on mouse hover in silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have some UI on client screen that contains some entities ,so on hover on that ui i need to show internal entity list on a pop up. how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

On hover you can use tooltip to show data that you want..please elaborate you question with some more demonstration

Comment: <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip x:Name="clusterDetail"                      
               Background="LightGray" >
                <StackPanel x:Name="stpDetail"/>                              but i am not able to access tool tip or stack panel from code behind
                 </ToolTip>
       </ToolTipService.ToolTip>